# Angular ELSE statement still executing even after IF is true, inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Angular 11 with Firestore, I am fetching data with subscribe method from api service, then using for loop to get object values, So, i can check if the value in collection exists. Even when the value exists, it first goes into the conditional if statement block as it should, but, then it also goes into else statement. I had also put break; in IF statement, but it didn't worked.

here is the code:

```
register() {
this.api.getLoginInfo().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(res).length; i++) {
    this.checkem = res[i].payload.doc.data()['email'];
    if (this.registerForm.value.email !== this.checkem) {
      alert("Registered Successfully");
      this.router.navigate(['/first']);
      localStorage.setItem("isLogged", "true");
    } else {
      console.log("Already Registered");
      alert("Already Registered!");
    }
  }
});
```

}

Api Service method:

```
getLoginInfo() {
return this.firestore.collection("users").snapshotChanges();}
```

Comment: what is coming in res?

Comment: I imagine should be `res[i].payload.doc.data['email']` -without `()`-, by the way write `console.log(res)` to know what is the response

Comment: @AakashGarg res data: https://ibb.co/MhwNynP

Comment: @Eliseo `res[i].payload.doc.data['email']` gave undefined result, and also alerted me 2 times, as there are 2 entries in user collection, also this is the res data: https://ibb.co/MhwNynP

Comment: the screenshot doesn't expose complete json. i don't see what is there in data() method. as checkem depends on that.

Comment: @AakashGarg Ok, I got it, there are 4 fields, which also includes "email", https://ibb.co/0qw7380

Comment: can you print checkem??

Comment: @AakashGarg yes https://ibb.co/x7xvnSX

Comment: value of email in form?

Comment: value of email in form was mohammadrokerya@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I solved the problem using firestore "where" query.

In my angular service the code is

```
getlogindetails(email) {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref
      .where('email', '==', email)
    ).get();
}
```

and In my component

```
register() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.api.getlogindetails(this.registerForm.value.email)
      .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
        if (!res.empty) {
          alert("Already Registered!");
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/first']);
          localStorage.setItem("isLogged", "true");
      });
  }
```